# Консольное приложение на c# . Возврат в меню после выполнения действия

Tags: c#, консоль

подскажите , что нужно сделать , что бы после выполнения действия со строкой программа возвращалась к выбору действия?

```
string str = "Hello guys!";
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.WriteLine("\nWhat we want to do with this string?");
Console.WriteLine("\nInsert   - 0; \nRemove   - 1; \nReaplace - 2; \nContains - 3; \nExit     - 4;\n"); // выбор действия со строкой.

int e = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (e == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of latter: ");  // место, в которое нужно вставить символы
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the letter , that we want to insert: "); // символ/ы который/ые вставляем
    string str1 = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine(str.Insert(i, "" + str1 + ""));

}
```

Comment: Почему бы просто не поместить ваш код в while?

Comment: `do {...} while (I == 0);` ?

Comment: Кстати слово `ребята` на английском будет `guys`, а не как у вас.

Comment: @ThusMad , не могли бы вы поподробней объяснить , как с помощью цикла while реализовать мою задачу?( вернуться к меню выбора действия со строкой)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В вашем случает код будет следующим:

```
        int e;
        string str = "Hello gues!";
        Console.WriteLine(str);

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nWhat we want to do with this string?");
            Console.WriteLine("\nInsert   - 0; \nRemove   - 1; \nReaplace - 2; \nContains - 3; \nExit     - 4;\n"); // выбор действия со строкой.

            e = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (e == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the position of latter: ");  // место, в которое нужно вставить символы
                int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the letter , that we want to insert: "); // символ/ы который/ые вставляем
                string str1 = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine(str.Insert(i, "" + str1 + ""));

            }
        } while (e != 4); // т.к 4 у вас условие выхода
```

Comment: а можно как-нибудь иначе написать  эту часть строки, а точнее именно второй параметр ( "" + str1 + "") -   

  Console.WriteLine(str.Insert(i, "" + str1 + ""));    ?

Comment: @AlekseiGrabor можно написать вот так вот str.Insert(i, str1)